# Quitar un <br> de un div a través de CSS?

Tags: css

estoy intentando quitar un salto de línea (`<br>`) dentro de un div que tiene una clase... y dentro hay un span.

Esto es así porque es un programa que haces objetos arrastrables etc. Que ocurre? que si pongo la clase y el br y display: none, no hace absolutamente nada. y queda como la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Arriba, lo tengo puesto para que haga el salto de línea y seas dos líneas de texto dentro del recuadro con un `<br>` pero al insertarlo, lo pone. Que puedo hacer? actualmente hago esto y nada:

```
<div style="width: 192px; height: 86px; position: absolute; left: 432px; top: 136px;" id="Text3" class="text_draggableGap_2lineas">
<span id="JPjhYe-1" class="ic_draggableGapFilled">Drag&amp;Drop 48px &lt;br&gt; Texto largo 2l.</span>
</div>

.clasediv span br{
display:none;
}
```

Te dejo una captura del código

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Podrías poner el código HTML generado? El css que utilizas debería ocultar los tags br, pero si realmente es un tag y no contenido del span no  debería mostrarse.

Comment: El problema es que te está codificando como código HTML el tag <br>: Drag&amp;Drop 48px &lt;br&gt; ¿Cómo insertas el contenido?

Comment: El contenido se insterta desde mAuthor, un gestor de contenidos, con una venta que añades texto plano que según donde esté dicho texto, lo interpreta como html, de ahí que me de el salto de línea, pero al incorporarse en el objeto siguiente, donde lo soltamos, ese objeto lo convierte en otra cosa, haciendo un "todo" dejando de ser html y mostrando el código así.

Realmente se como se quita el br en html normal, de ahí que el post pueda parecer sencillo pero no hay manera (y no puedo meter Javascript) de eliminar ese necesario y útil salto de línea...

Alguna sugerencia? Mil gracias!.

Comment: Prueba de generar el div con un width menor y sin el `<br>` para que el texto por si sólo venga hacia abajo.

Comment: @djohny Como te comentó Asier, no estás insertando un `<br>`, sino que lo toma como texto. No conozco mAuthor, pero ¿probaste poniendo un salto de línea (tecla `Enter`, `Shift` + `Enter`, o alguna combinación así)?

Answer (score 1):

Ponle esta propiedad a los 3 elementos:

```
display:inline-block;
```

Answer (score 0):

El siguiente código `css` debería funcionar:

```
td div,
div br {
    display: inline;
}
```

Sin embargo debería considerar, eliminar los elementos `div` vacíos.